# How to reset env for cucumber-reports through commands in karate

Tags: cucumber, karate, gherkin, cucumber-junit

I have one runner file in karate to generate cucumber reports

```
public void genrateFinalReport() {
        System.setProperty("karate.env", "pre_production"); // ensure reset if other tests (e.g. mock) had set env in CI
        Results results = Runner.parallel(getClass(), 1);
        generateReport(results.getReportDir());
        assertTrue(results.getErrorMessages(), results.getFailCount() == 0);
    }
```

in this i have set enviroment to pre_production.

I want to change or modify environment through the command line.

To change the environment through command line I'm using below command

```
mvn test -Dkarate.env=production -Dtest=PcadSanityTestReport
```

But by default pre_production environment is getting passed

```
com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: pre_production
```

can anyone help how to pass env in the command line or do I need to create a different runner for different env

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand. You override the value with

```
System.setProperty("karate.env", "pre_production");
```

just before you launch the tests, yet you expect the value to be different?

Edit:
Since you seem to want a default value for `env`, you should do that in karate-config.js

```
var env = karate.env;
//here, you can override env with a default value if the value isn't an authorized one :
if (env != "pre_production" && env != "production"){
    env = "pre_production";
}
```

Comment: Yes i want to override the value. How to override the value through command line

Comment: Your command line works. Just remove `System.setProperty("karate.env", "pre_production");`

Comment: I also updated my post to show you how to use a default value if `env` is not an authorized value, directly in `karate-config.js`